# Array element addition

Tags: java, arrays

This may be a completely trivial question but i cannot find any documentation on this...
I want to find the sum of two individual array elements for example....

```
array3[x] = array1[y] + array2[z]
```

when I do something like this, the answer is y and z combined. how would one find the sum of numbers y & z and not the conjoined string.
Sorry if this is exceedingly trivial but i could not find a post asking this myself.

in summary if I have an array eg: a[1,2,5,9] & b[8,6,7,2] & c[]

```
c[0] = a[0] + b[0]
System.out.println(c[0]);
 "9"
```

Comment: You need an `int[]` and not a `String[]`.

Comment: paste relevant code, type of c, a and b

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: If it needs to be a string, then you will have to convert the numbers that you want to sum to integers to do a numeric operation, then convert it back to a string.

Comment: I am outputting from a file so it needs to be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use string array you can do

```
String[] a={"1","2"};
String[] b={"1","2"};
String[] c=new String[1];
c[0]=String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a[1])+Integer.parseInt(b[1]));
System.out.println(c[0]);  // outputs 4
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/tjOLHB)

Note: but be sure that string array contains integer value otherwise you will end up with `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `String[]` and you are doing this:

```
final String a = "a";
final String b = "b";
final String ab = a + b;
System.out.println(ab); // "ab"
```

You need to use *numbers* if you want to carry out *numeric* operations:

```
final int a = 8;
final int b = 1;
final int ab = a + b;
System.out.println(ab); // 9
```

If you want to do this with `String` you have to convert:

```
int[] sums = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.length, b.length))
        .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(a[i] + Integer.parseInt(b[i])))
        .toArray();
```

If you want a `String[]` as a result:

```
String[] sums = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.length, b.length))
        .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(a[i] + Integer.parseInt(b[i])))
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the String to Integer, Then add.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] a = {"1","2","5","9"};
            String[] b = {"8","6","7","2"};

            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a[0])+ Integer.parseInt(b[0]));

        }
```